# Which configuration to use for small server running under Proxmox?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualization, nas

I'm here to ask your suggestions for the following setup and really looking forward for some cases from real experience.

I'm planning to launch small server in my company for the following needs:

- Jenkins for some builds
- file storage (like NAS)
- SVN repository
- OpenVPN server

For the main OS I would like to choose Proxmox to create separated VMs for each point.

 Server has the following configuration:

- CPU: Intel Core i7-8700 3.2 GHz/6core/SVGA UHD Graphics 630/1.5+12Mb/65W/8 GT/s LGA1151
- RAM: 24Gb
- SSD 120 Gb SATA 6Gb/s Kingston A400 2.5" TLC
- 2 x HDD 4 Tb SATA 6Gb/s Seagate Enterprise Capacity  3.5" 7200rpm 128Mb
- MB: GIGABYTE GA-Z370-HD3 (RTL) LGA1151  3xPCI-E DVI+HDMI GbLAN SATA RAID ATX 4DDR4

So the idea is to install Proxmox on SSD drive and combine 2x4Tb to RAID1.

As I have lack of experience, can anyone suggest:
 - what to choose HW or SW RAID 
 - Is it ok to have file storage on the same drive where other VMs will be deployed?

P.S. If you have some suggestions how to build this setup in better way I will really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: I think shopping suggestions are off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Darren the question about getting experience from people who already met this, I think this is acceptable here. I'm not asking which HW to buy, I'm asking about the best way to implement based on people experience